# How to get previous 5 days date from given date?

Tags: flutter, dart

- How to get previous 5 days date(30/11/2020) from given date?
- How to get previous 5 months from given date?

Comment: You must try it yourself first and share some code here.

Comment: @harundemir918 sure.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a negative Duration:

```
DateTime nowFiveDaysAgo = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: -5));
```

Answer (score 0):

> ****Used simple code example - to show previous 5 days date :-****

```
  void calucateDateRange() {
    final currentDate = DateTime.now();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      final date = currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: i));
      print(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(date));
    }
  }
```

> ****Example - to show next 5 days date :-****

```
  void calucateDateRange() {
    final currentDate = DateTime.now();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      final date = currentDate.add(Duration(days: i));
      print(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(date));
    }
  }
```

***Note : you can use DateFormat as per you required.***